# What is the motion path of each point on the rope? How is the tension calculated?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, string

[image]

The blue line is the rope. Suppose point A of the rope moves upward and point B does not move, what is the motion path of each point on the rope? How is the tension calculated?

Answer (score 1):

Simply moving one end of a rope with respect to the other won’t necessarily cause tension in the rope. The rope would have to be stretched beyond its initial length. If you pinned B and pulled from A, the rope would not look like your graphic. It would follow a straight line. If you knew the Young’s modulus of the rope you could calculate stress as follows:

$$\sigma = E \epsilon = E \frac{\Delta l}{l_0}$$

With the stress and cross-sectional area of the rope, tension can be calculated as follows:

$$\sigma = \frac{T}{A} \implies T = \sigma A$$

To find the shape of a rope which is not in tension with endpoints $A(x_0,y_0)$ and $B(x_1,y_1)$, I'd assume you'd find the path between A and B with arc length equal to the rope's initial length which minimizes the rope's gravitational potential.

Comment: Check out this link: [Equilibrium Shape of a Hanging Rope](http://www.dmf.unicatt.it/divulgazione/mateott/catenaria/catenary/catenary.htm).

Comment: The rope is under gravity. Won't gravity cause the tension of the rope? Lift A up. What is the motion path of a point on the rope?

Comment: I guess you could consider the self-weight of the rope, but the self-weight of a typical rope would cause negligible stress. Also, if you were to consider self-weight, this would be a bending situation. Tension/compression would vary along the cross-section. Hang the rope vertically, then it would be uniaxial tension. Finding the motion would involve calculus of variations, as shown in the link above, with a function describing the motion of A as an integration limit instead of a stationary point

Comment: When A moves upward, what is the motion path of a point on the rope?

Comment: It is whatever calculus of variations would predict it to be. Check out the link above.